# Secure way to store user account credit in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design

In a Rails 4 application, I need to implement one-time payment system and add credits to user accounts.
Considering integrity and security, what is the best practice to store the user credit data? 
Should I only implement an attribute to users' model or something else? 
NOTE1: I use a custom payment system and none of the regular payment systems are of my use.
NOTE2: As it seems, using multiple databases in a rails application is not an standard.

Comment: There's a reason developers are willing to pay companies like Stripe or PayPal to handle transactions for them. Are you ready to pay for [PCI](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/faq/) certification and then recertify periodically?

Comment: Suppose that it is not about payment, how do you protect an important attribute in a table?

Comment: @ErfanSh.z. see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To securely store users' credit data in your database, you will need to have PCI-DSS certification first and foremost. You can read more about it [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard).
To avoid that, best way would be to have a payment gateway store it for you, from where you can use the credentials for payments as required.

EDIT: 
As per your comment for protecting important attributes NOT related to payment, you should try the [Strongbox gem](https://github.com/spikex/strongbox).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean by "credit data" is not a credit card number, but an integer indicating how much credit a user has in your own "currency". As long as it's not absolutely confidential how much credit a user has, I don't think storing is a problem. It's rather about updating it.

- Make sure it's stored in a central place, like the database. The session is not a good place for that.
- Make sure to avoid race conditions when removing credit, read more about it [here](http://www.leighhalliday.com/avoid-race-conditions-with-postgres-locks)